# Evaluating a residue at a second order poles

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I need help with this residue. $z=i\pi/2$ is a second order pole. When i apply the regular procedure, it tells me that the residue is infinity, but I know this is wrong. How do i deal with second order poles?

$$\operatorname{Res}_{z=i\pi/2}\operatorname{sech}^2(z)$$

Comment: What do you mean by "regular procedure"?

Comment: The limit as z approaches the pole of (z-pole)f(z) @Desperado

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2315871/42969

Comment: Think in terms of the Laurent series. You have to take $$\lim_{z\to z_0} \dfrac d{dz} [(z-z_0)^2*f(z)]$$ Check it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near $\frac{\pi i}2$, you have\begin{align}\cosh^2(z)&=\cosh^2\left(\left(z-\frac{\pi i}2\right)+\frac{\pi i}2\right)\\&=\sinh^2\left(z-\frac{\pi i}2\right).\end{align}Since $\sinh^2$ is an even function which maps $0$ into $0$, its Taylor series centered at $0$ is of the form $a_2z^2+a_4z^4+\cdots.$So,\begin{align}\operatorname{sech}^2(z)&=\frac1{\cosh^2(z)}\\&=\frac1{a_2\left(z-\frac{\pi i}2\right)^2+a_4\left(z-\frac{\pi i}2\right)^4+\cdots},\end{align}and, since this is an even function, the residue at $z-\frac{\pi i}2$, which is the coefficient of $\frac1{z-\pi i/2}$, is $0$.